# Can photocells (PN Juctions) be stacked?

Tags: photometry

Can photocells (the PN junctions) be stacked (3) on top of each other (not just side-by-side) to let each PN junction produce electrical energy from the visible light, Infrared (IR) and ultraviolet light (UV)?
[image]

Comment: Depends on how transparent they are.

Comment: If you want more energy per area, then it might be wise to put them like this \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ instead of ----------------

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can. This is called a [multi-junction solar cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-junction_solar_cell). From the Wikipedia article:

> Currently, the best lab examples of traditional crystalline silicon solar cells have efficiencies between 20% and 25%, while lab examples of multi-junction cells have demonstrated performance over 46% under concentrated sunlight. Commercial examples of tandem cells are widely available at 30% under one-sun illumination, and improve to around 40% under concentrated sunlight. However, this efficiency is gained at the cost of increased complexity and manufacturing price. To date, their higher price and higher price-to-performance ratio have limited their use to special roles, notably in aerospace where their high power-to-weight ratio is desirable.

The individual junctions are not connected in parallel, as you propose, but in series.

On “transparency”:

> Conveniently, light of a particular wavelength does not interact strongly with materials that are of bigger bandgap. This means that you can make a multi-junction cell by layering the different materials on top of each other, shortest wavelengths (biggest bandgap) on the "top" and increasing through the body of the cell.

Comment: Could fiber optic cable be used to feed light to multi-junction solar cell, and still have a good theoretical efficiency?

Comment: @Bill That's a further question which I cannot help you with. Posting questions in comments isn't a good idea because fewer people will see them.